# Uniqueness of two side zeroes of binary operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups, binary-operations, magma

I came across the following fact in group theory:

> Two-sided identity of binary operation is unique.

Does the similar statement for two sided zero also holds? :

> Two-sided zero of binary operation is unique.

I feel yes. Because say if we have two distinct two sided zeroes $y$ and $z$ for operation $*$, then we will have,

$y*z=y$  ($y$ being zero)
$y*z=z$  ($z$ being zero)

Does this implies $y=z$. Is this right way to reason out with?

Comment: "The" identity in a group is **always** related to **the identity under the group's operation*. If you talk of "a zero element", it is because in that group the operation is called "addition" and its unit element behaves as the usual zero we know from the integers, say.

Comment: Semigroup theory might interest you.

Comment: @DonAntonio By a "zero element" the asker does ***not*** mean "an additive identity element", he means an "absorbing element". This is clear from the line "$y*z=y$ ($y$ being zero)".

Comment: @bof ohhh does "an additive identity" also called zero? Actually I didnt get what DonAntonio was talking about...

Comment: @bof Perhaps that is so,  but then the OP doesn't abide by usual standard notation and names. Hard to guess what he really means, as "absorbing element" is nothing I, personally, can connect with basic group theory axioms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. If $0, 0'$ are two two-sided zeros, then

$$\underbrace{0=00'}_{0\text{ a left zero}}=\overbrace{00'=0'}^{0'\text{ a right zero}},$$

meaning that such zeros are unique by transitivity.

You had this yourself: you just needed transitivity of equality.

To learn more about such things, consider Semigroup Theory or Magma Theory.